# How to show popup window instead redirect to facebook?

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js, facebook-authentication

I use [this tutorial](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/) to authenticate users via facebook. But I need to need to show popup window instead redirecting to facebook site.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried some javascript (eg [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open)) to open /auth/facebook in a popup instead of just using a link?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it not possible to do, After facebook login, it will redirect to the redirect url which we given at the time of app creation.

Comment: I need do it not after facebook login but before

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to put together a project that uses Node.js, PassportJS with Facebook, MongoDB, REquireJS and Backbone.js

https://github.com/rafaelfaria/PassportJS-Facebook-Client-Auth

Check it out. I hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a display:"popup" property while using the authentication, following is the code snippet -

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { display: 'popup' }));
```